# How can i know how is my job run in aws beanstalk?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jobs

I have a process that run every one hour. 
The problem that I can't really know how is my job actually run? what server is making the job run every hour and how can I edit that configuration? I want to know that because I have 2 servers and both of them running the job and I want to cancel one of them so how can I do that?(there is an option in application properties?)
I'm using `Elastic beanstalk` and `java spring`.

p.s i don't want to terminate the server i want  to make the `server` stop running spesefic job

Comment: put loggers inside the method.

Comment: You will be able to cancel/delete the unused elasticbean environment from aws console. You can use cloud watch for monitoring logs

Comment: I'm trying to make the server stop running spesefic job. how loggers can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

To terminate an environment

1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
2. From the region list, select the region that includes the
   environment that want to terminate.
3. From the Elastic Beanstalk console applications page, click the name
   of the environment that you want to terminate.

   [image]
4. Click Actions and the select Terminate Environment.
   [image]
5. Confirm that you are terminating the correct environment and then click Terminate.

**To pause the environment**

1. Open the Elastic Bean environment you want to pause and go to
   “Configuration”
2. On the Scaling card, click on the Gear icon to change its settings
   [image]
3. in the “Auto Scaling” options, set the “Minimum instance count” to 0, and the “Maximum instance count” to 0
4. then **Apply**

**Monitoring logs**

You can use **Cloudwatch** for this purpose.

`Amazon CloudWatch` is a monitoring service for AWS cloud resources and the applications you run on AWS. You can use Amazon CloudWatch to collect and track metrics, collect and monitor log files, set alarms, and automatically react to changes in your AWS resources.

for more info read this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.terminating.html)

**To delete specific version from beanstalk**

[image]

Comment: i don't want to terminate the server i just want from this server to stop running the spesific job

Comment: @tal Shani Just edited my answer. If you dont want to terminate the event you can pause it

Comment: I still want the server work and run the other jobs, just not this specific job

Comment: Did you check the undeploy?

Comment: no. whats does it mean? I'm kind of new on this issue

Comment: Actually we can delete the specfic version of application from beanstalk using aws  console. so the server will be up and the job will be down

Comment: how can i do that can u upload pictures?

Comment: im not sure that this is the solution. it will not stop my job

Comment: Can you please edit the question and post some more info about your job and the way you deploy that into AWS. I think it's a spring application deployed into beanstalk..are you using AWS console?

Comment: yes I'm using aws. I'm running my process by doing this : 
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *")
  fun startProcessing(){

    this.processCompliance.process()
  }

Comment: If you set your cron like below it wont execute further. @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 5 31 2 ?")You have two instance you can try this with one server.

Answer (score 0):

I would **NOT** use an Elastic Beanstalk environment to schedule a cron job. There are tools available to manage jobs running on a schedule.

> You can use a [Beanstalk Worker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) to deploy **event / schedule** driven Jobs.
>
> I personally would use [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) to write a [Dags](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#it-s-a-dag-definition-file) and tasks using python scripting language. Can connect any task to your aws account using [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) AWS SDK